# What should I replace num with?

Tags: c++, sum, product

I'm trying to write a program that will determine whether both the sum and product of two integers is either even or odd.

Everything seems to be fine, except when I run the program, it comes out: "The product of 2 and 3 is 5 and is even." Even?

Why does it say even when it should be odd? Now from what I am understanding, it is reading `num` since I put `(num%2==0)` and that's why it is saying even. How can I make it read the outcome of two numbers (sum/product)?

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
        int num; 
        cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
        cin >> num;

        int num2;
        cout << "Please enter another integer: ";
        cin >> num2;

    if ( num % 2 == 0 )
    {
        cout << "The product of " << num << " and " << num2 << " is " << num*num2 << " and is even." << endl;
        cout << "The sum of " << num << " and " << num2 << " is " << num+num2 << " and is even." << endl;
    } 

    else
    {
        cout << "The product of " << num << " and " << num2 << " is " << num*num2 << " and is odd." << endl;
        cout << "The sum of " << num << " and " << num2 << " is " << num+num2 << " and is odd." << endl;   
    } 
        return (0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You just checking if `num` is even. Instead, you should calculate the product and the sum, and check them both:

```
int sum = num + num2;
int product = num * num2;

if (sum % 2 == 0 && product % 2 == 0) {
   cout << sum and product are both even << endl;
} else {
   cout << sum and product are not both even << endl;
}
```